# Create multiple dataframes out of several dataframes multipling value according to "Base"-Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I got a dictionary of dataframes ,`dataframes`, which are time based profiles with values `x` and `y` for each point in time. The following shows the dictionary and one dataframe of this dictionary

`dataframes={'SG1':Dataframe, 'SG2':Dataframe, 'SG3':Dataframe, 'SG4':Dataframe, 'SG5':Dataframe}`

| Date | Time | value x | value y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2018 | 0:00 | 0.45 | 0.11 |
| 01.01.2018 | 0:15 | 0.42 | 0.20 |

With those I want to create a dictionary of new dataframes; `dataframes2`, where the values `x` and `y` are a sum of the old dataframes multiplied with a value.
This value is contained in another nested dictionary:

`base_dict={'area1':{'SG1':0.0,'SG2':1.0}, 'area2':{'SG1':1.0,'SG2':0.0}}`

( note: I shorted the dictionary)

At the end `dataframes2` should look like this:

`dataframes2`={'area1':Dataframe, 'area2':Dataframe}
While area1 looks like this:

| Date | Time | value x | value y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2018 | 0:00 | 0.0 * SG1 value x+1.0* SG2 value x | 0.0 * SG1 value y+1.0 * SG2 value y |
| 01.01.2018 | 0:15 | 0.0 * SG1 value x+ 1.0 * SG2 value x | 0.0 * SG1 value y+1.0 * SG2 value y |

I think of using mutliple for loops, but I am not really sure where to start here.
Can you help me?

Comment: where does the area variable come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:This is based on Darina's Answer. Since this seems to much to put it in the comments I wrote it as a different answer. I changed the code, since Darina's answer a series object was created and the dataframes resultet in a size of 1*1, which is not the goal here.

```
`for area, vals in base_dict.items():
  df_keys = list(vals.keys())
    d=dataframes[df_keys[0]]['Date']
    t=dataframes[dfs_keys[0]]['Time']
    x=dataframes[df_keys[0]]['value x']*vals[df_keys[0]] + dataframes[df_keys[1]]['value x']*vals[df_keys[1]]
    y=dataframes[df_keys[0]]['value y']*vals[df_keys[0]] + dataframes[df_keys[1]]['value y']*vals[df_keys[1]]
    dataframes2[area] = pd.concat([d.to_frame(name='Date'),t.to_frame(name='Time'),x.to_frame(name='value x'),y.to_frame(name='value y')], axis=1)`
```

I avoided `.Date` and `.Time` since the datatype of the `'Date'` and `'Time'` values was not `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

If all your data frames have the same dates and times, you can do it in one for loop, iterating over keys and values of `base_dict` and creating an entry in `dataframes2` for each key:

```
for area, vals in base_dict.items():
    df_keys = list(vals.keys())
    dataframes2[area] = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dataframes[df_keys[0]].Date, 
                                      'Time': dataframes[df_keys[0]].Time, 
                                      'value x': dataframes[df_keys[0]]['value x']*vals[df_keys[0]] + dataframes[df_keys[1]]['value y']*vals[df_keys[1]], 
                                      'value y': accordingly
```

If the timestamps are different, you can do a similar approach, but instead of just creating a new data frame, you'll need to work with merges.

Edit: We had this discussion in the comments but since I cannot post a code sample there, here is a full minimal example of my code that does not return a 1x1 Dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5), 'y': range(5, 10), 'Date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(10,15), 'y': range(15,20), 'Date': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5)})
dataframes2 = {}
dataframes={'SG1': df1, 'SG2': df2}
base_dict={'area1':{'SG1':0.0,'SG2':1.0}, 'area2':{'SG1':1.0,'SG2':0.0}}
for area, vals in base_dict.items():
    df_keys = list(vals.keys())
    dataframes2[area] = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dataframes[df_keys[0]].Date, 
                                      'value x': dataframes[df_keys[0]]['x']*vals[df_keys[0]] + dataframes[df_keys[1]]['y']*vals[df_keys[1]]})
```

Result:

```
{'area1':         Date  value x
 0 2018-01-01     15.0
 1 2018-01-02     16.0
 2 2018-01-03     17.0
 3 2018-01-04     18.0
 4 2018-01-05     19.0,
 'area2':         Date  value x
 0 2018-01-01      0.0
 1 2018-01-02      1.0
 2 2018-01-03      2.0
 3 2018-01-04      3.0
 4 2018-01-05      4.0}
```

Comment: when applying this I get the error: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: Yeah, my bad, you'll need to convert `df_keys` to list first. I've edited my original answer.

Comment: your using indexes 1 and 2, for the example. How would you change that if the dataframes have the size (96,4) ? (sry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: The indexes are for the keys in the dictionary, not in the data frames. Try to run the loop and print the value of `df_keys` to understand.

Comment: Also if my answers are helpful please consider upvoting or accepting them.

Comment: I Used your code, and it always told me that there is a missmach in length. So I checked what kind of dataframe is created if I just use: `x=pd.DataFrame({'value x': dataframes[df_keys[0]]['value x']*vals[df_keys[0]] + dataframes[df_keys[1]]['value x']*vals[df_keys[1]]})` and it just creates a 1*1 Dataframe

Comment: as soon as I am able to upvote you will get one

Comment: Are you sure? I just wrote a full minimal example using my code and it returns a regular dataframe.

Comment: I've edited my answer to contain the example since I cannot put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is even possible to use a comprehension here. The trick is that you can use operations on full dataframes, provided they have same indexes and columns. So if you *hide* the `Date` and `Time` columns in the index, everything works fine:

```
dataframes2 ={k: sum(dataframes[name].set_index(['Date ', 'Time ']) * coeff 
                     for name, coeff in d.items()).reset_index()
              for k,d in base_dict.items()}
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty neat solution. However, Date and Time need to be seperately stored in the dataframe, since this form is important for the import in another software.  Anyway is it possible to use a object type as index? (Time and Date are stored as objects. Even if this is not nice, there is a reason for that) Thank you!

Comment: My code contains a `reset_index` for that reason: the Date and Time are made back plain columns after the operation and the dataframes from `dataframe2` have exactly the same structures as the ones in `dataframes`